# Why my website emails go to SPAM box HOTMAIL

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, imap, postfix-mta

We have a small company, we send sometimes few emails.

All these emails are considered as safe emails by all emails provider, only HOTMAIL.

How can i know the reason why HOTMAIL consider our emails as SPAM ?

Understand our Outlook / Hotmail / Office365 Deliverability Issues with X-Forefront-Antispam-Report ?

You can find bellow an exemple of an email classified by HOTMAIL as SPAM :

```
Received: from HE1EUR04HT080.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
(2603:10b6:a03:100::41) by BYAPR17MB2341.namprd17.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS
via BYAPR08CA0028.NAMPRD08.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Wed, 5 Dec 2018 10:35:04 +0000
Received: from HE1EUR04FT013.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
(10.152.26.59) by HE1EUR04HT080.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
(10.152.26.72) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384) id 15.20.1404.13; Wed, 5 Dec
2018 10:35:03 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is xx.xxx.xx.xx)
smtp.mailfrom=xxxxxxxxxx.com; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
header.d=xxxxxxxxxx.com;hotmail.com; dmarc=temperror action=none
header.from=xxxxxxxxxx.com;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of xxxxxxxxxx.com designates
xx.xxx.xx.xx as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
client-ip=xx.xxx.xx.xx; helo=xxxxxxxxxx.com;
Received: from xxxxxxxxxx.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx) by
HE1EUR04FT013.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.26.126) with Microsoft SMTP
Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
15.20.1404.13 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 5 Dec 2018 10:35:01 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker: OriginalChecksum:AB1002FDAF6A587890EE7D690A8B7C0533694AA27CC8CD5DD9887E9B10F6A6AA;UpperCasedChecksum:2C9C5779BC7CA07579C2ABCCDCC6DC4EF6E1F5707AEA3F3E3B8FB9DB8A5964FE;SizeAsReceived:1060;Count:12
Received: from authenticated-user (PRIMARY_HOSTNAME [PUBLIC_IP])
by xxxxxxxxxx.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 3042C13B6
for <prenom.nom@hotmail.com>; Wed, 5 Dec 2018 10:35:01 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Wed, 05 Dec 2018 10:35:00 +0000
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="--=_RainLoop_184_159261189.1544006100"
From: xxxx.xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com
Message-ID: <1d5dbc12b0ad9f393b60bdcf281453d4@xxxxxxxxxx.com>
Reply-To: xxxx.xxxx@yahoo.fr
Subject: Mail de test
To: "prenom nom" <prenom.nom@hotmail.com>
X-Spamd-Bar: /
Authentication-Results-Original: auth=pass smtp.auth=xxxx.xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com
smtp.mailfrom=xxxx.xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=xxxxxxxxxx.com;
s=dkim; t=1544006101;
h=from:reply-to:subject:date:message-id:to:mime-version:content-type;
bh=rUWyfwQa5tHrCBIwEq0ehhhrOAC/x3JYLLdxQgyDPyI=;
b=fevC4RxDsG9+KynrDFzJZtm/NreksALp7vHODFCUspUglru5PsIM0ta0JUCaNpAldMCbpo
Fp7dWa84dYFBnh85l9oV9HFpzHTgCzk/v63Hjw5ggxJJq41e46mlgr3wbdJjb8gDNcE4gc
AV9BATZpIZH8OKpXgtOk53N+laqJRZg=
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 12
Return-Path: xxxx.xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 05 Dec 2018 10:35:01.9575
(UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 2:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 4730759b-0399-41af-5552-08d65a9d5017
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;HE1EUR04FT013;1:f6d7toPjHds79kfjb8F8a92RxuOXFF60QrueiBIAci0rI6sqqY48Bzu8uaNPzyL+FT+X9g/kG7bzmFi2V3HyDeZeMuGeuUuP9oSB16V/YB9PGJWjCgb0fJhRv68sm8lk
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
HE1EUR04FT013.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 12/5/2018 10:31:45 AM
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 4730759b-0399-41af-5552-08d65a9d5017
X-Microsoft-Antispam:
BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(2390098)(5000110)(711020)(4605076)(610169)(650170)(651021)(8291501071);SRVR:HE1EUR04HT080;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
1;HE1EUR04HT080;3:DybF6SUpFveGAxx8na3Ize3Nkt11joOtHTmP4K19riue2nfmCDbAyWtEYCFb39NFLsV0PICKRCZizik1veZYKZZAcyTwiQmwBg5eXjW0fGglhIgvt9/rQ5isFDOhdIvBHmH3ibQzaj7ZwH7Iir5xLlUh6KuQjK4wqbZ70xNx7L9xtCkl1KIZn9nyqt1CvAT8C1eCok0fU+ox4kGY8NzL87N2fRqer12pTDSEatEWoGcBosOnaKKbfJQZ8xn3738k09JlzAajuEghTgVNfAM3qpJyVk3ZD4FWpYcStFs23qSty17srM/Tayf11c8uB46uix5Y7KnAXa9rNRUfMONZBA==;25:/SJAdxq4u4Qs1hsqopWz0P0KJHrriehmS29nQXtMgNdyC/cclr2pHh4viLne8HpxsTcz6FrSKBu+mJqB84LON4ctSh+BHbxE3WmdWSndOZn+1S4dDARLgb+uzcn/JbOCCaYuIG98V+QZ8fbqqyYkamo9JsOmiGCMTQIDAQD/cJrgvbrRUfSu6gkYhzYAn4vP2SwFf5pxMZ4WrWMmc0bNrPEUOSvG6VFM5JlGO2Os6dlpTbb6TTRv2l7y9BfvANVnXEwB53LOCclUNVKFf6+2fz9bKKw+VIy5/swsy2z+h8n/WPKoqM92Mpdnoq6LFItoTKRqWwQDqvv2F3nO0OKQmA==;31:dOrm256zuEt/hE/ekHqoTmIFEXc3zHxEZayzOO42bqB36gH75boqRurWRKHauLRLvCYkTvXymjaXQsUJKVXs80ws5rCMaT7QiwMplBdg0VWdDFZvwjh/tt2Nex/4a7uaO8g5M9D8rS0CXCrpSVzTp+Jga6sxIzEMgtq3OlmJIhulvmOsoSld1HvPcOGpXMeRZZD2PsotmP2Tn9ElHF5AmGU4ViCtza4/J9FB+E4A2W0=
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: HE1EUR04HT080:
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx
X-SID-PRA: xxxx.xxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.COM
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(444111751)(6300000075)(1201097)(52401380)(52601095)(52505095)(52406095)(52305095)(52206095)(88860335)(82015058);SRVR:HE1EUR04HT080;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:HE1EUR04HT080;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
1;HE1EUR04HT080;4:bokg6rTSYvxEH9tWbCTyUYr0q5d15BPnt3b/6NKV1aU47utLwxgQ3Uen6CF95MioWJ7vvtnrkzk/fZP/MnWwvPlt2LRJsAvjCcM+DhRB4Xe2oCPUZzR/2mfZz5VsEfraEDaZ8s4GsoKPIKsJ4B6Y9xz+xUec4kc3cmIHh5SEfv+AXcHtdM1TKdA4usesZy47wEFH2rlFaKJEJxViqyBx/+26SDBbLD9PQP2hUUDWn8YbKAzJz7kR23nsBU5mvnQitvIfh5Bt3+zV2wg1zwahMA==;6:l6ijCjczte/M+2grONf/7pGyIkA1XNf4ID15Esb3yess1e9qhWDPeZwXlbH4hdWZK9DAagKkup3nQoQmaHFWM1UyZrK/yXBDWwbu2CYkI0LYD0/x2bGkNcnFXUuZvjEwhBI276G4Q9s1niDBXrLyCy6nrroKStX+XVdwQJRN+SOmn1nRBk4ve83RRKErll45NODrJ1gs+ohoPuPKKE+WsiHVqPqXc8/tAYQ2+6rDDDuSe1JW8tbwG6GPQTgmTB4VCZCmDHE+OYv/AwUI9E5/tvjDaR+AUGfmxkNEfAGy5FaGIpPyc5ooj2Ccoc78uJ1uSJSG0PaRkC9BpBqzDAyDCUMtNiYKxkmT/BX7G7izvr4YSz3/2IjYroc3BRaBgR1ysgDdJaNQxMdgvdSLf+QT7GAjoPlzHjg5kdbhboJ21LA7FUbD38w9sCeLL/quipitUon1NWPG86s5Sqvk2Dlp0A==;5:Swo0LieNeMdG7TItYBICIBs0+ruylDAdbXBR0mvw8RBGaL8cuIubr/SDBiw8BowyZ1QpMwH8zEyR1DPU0K18Po7sIcdApik4BOkjw3sVVlUr8Q0i6hFhkjWbbhCTcJLzQ2vHbiB9TubWWw5v9b1bNTvzvsYSCsmct8RLj7klb+Y=
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
1;HE1EUR04HT080;7:/enTEOqI+9/YUuE8ZQ9zGk1y/OeSFzGo3DLWTFNT1Df2M9R68+jdV3s+KWz8wPKd8cpou9+NhTU/Ly60rQh2wB1nSL9Z+W+mqZLXhdfPmN+sIfwIAOXAY74iQZfUMqyY5fDb4d5X13fGQzKO8ZFERQ==
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 05 Dec 2018 10:35:01.8638
(UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 4730759b-0399-41af-5552-08d65a9d5017
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
c001924d-3e68-4f40-89c2-901a49278da7
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: HE1EUR04HT080
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.1382293
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.1404.009
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
1;BYAPR17MB2341;27: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
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;ENG:(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6375004)(4950130)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;
X-Message-Info:
qoGN4b5S4yog6nY042nLw3cqoJY/BsdeIdvpFyeEToIfBWdMiTy9ohwkOjOHX/mmYDuIIXAZuntJB/jcvsI8N12HJabUBoRzEX6xvbe2KE26SyeTZwImTZfxGqX28h5yd+X+vl4xYK4JrDiB4OS5lY4EIUJKI6TMjc2520XsSe62AVW/zBal1X8WxWxQRjLLJ2OD1DdMGUwrpwctIvbXmA==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
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
```

Comment: May be an issue with dmarc? `dmarc=temperror action=none
header.from=xxxxxxxxxx.com`  You don't have to have dmarc though.  I only have SPF on my domain and I don't go to spam

Comment: Maybe this link will help for you: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/my-email-address-is-being-seen-as-junkspam-by/497c4f02-bc6d-4a32-bc19-69199ad9ae20

Comment: This question should not have been asked (or answered) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Blacklisting of a sending ip or your sending domain could be a probable reason. And it is that Hotmail smtp server has only blacklisted your domain /Ip . Try changing your sending Ip or the domain and see if it lands in the spam or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like checking my domain's send reputation on a site like [Sender Score](https://www.senderscore.org/). That will tell you if you've been blacklisted. Then I would reach out to the [Outlook postmaster](https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/pm/) to see what I can do to fix my errors. I also would really double check how my emails look in Hotmail, user engagement counts in many spam scores, and if the content doesn't look good it, users could be deleting it or marking it as spam.